# Android get twitter Followers List ?

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to get the  twitter friends list . For that have Referred the following url . From that i have got the group of friends ids . How to get the each id's details . please advice me .

Thanks 
Rajesh K

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids

Answer (score 0):

Refer to
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friendships/lookup

Also, Twitter API version 1 is deprecated. You should use version 1.1.

Comment: if i ues the url which provided by the twitter giving the following issue . please advice me {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

Comment: Hi i have tried with the normal pc browser . there it shows above issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:-

```
TwitterCursorList<TwitterUser> friendsList = service.ListFriends(new ListFriendsOptions{ Cursor = -1 });

while (friendsList.NextCursor != 0)
{
 friendsList = service.ListFriends(new ListFriendsOptions
 {
  Cursor = friendsList.NextCursor
 });

}
```

The above code will give you all twitter friends.

Comment: Can you please tell what is service in this code sample ?
Is it statusesService ?